# Is there a known origin for the Beaufort motto "Mutare vel Timere Sperno"?

Tags: england, war-of-the-roses

The [House of Beaufort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Beaufort) (and cadet branch the [House of Somerset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_of_Beaufort)) use the motto **"Mutare vel timere sperno"** *("I scorn to change or to fear")*.

I assume it references the Beaufort loyalty to and support of the House of Lancaster in the War of the Roses, originating perhaps in the time of [Edmund Beaufort, 2nd Duke of Somerset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Beaufort,_2nd_Duke_of_Somerset), but cannot find any mention of its origin.